# Binary Tree Level Order Traversal Using Queue in C

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

I am fairly new to C. I started studying data structures and was okay with linked lists, stacks, and queues. Right now I am implementing BST's and they seem to be pretty complicated. Here I tried writing code for Level Order Transversal and I am not getting the required output. 
**Please help me fix it.** 
It showed no errors. On running the program, I get infinite 'G' as my output. I expected to get all the characters (which I had input in the main function) to be printed in some order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node* right;
    struct Node* left;

    };

void enq(struct Node* temproot);
struct Node* deq();
struct Node* Insert(struct Node* ,char x);
struct Node* newNode (char data);
void LevelOrder(struct Node* root);

struct Node* front = NULL;
struct Node* rear = NULL;

int main()
{

    struct Node* root;
    root = NULL;
    root = Insert(root,'F');
    root = Insert(root,'B');
    root = Insert(root,'C');
    root = Insert(root,'D');
    root = Insert(root,'E');
    root = Insert(root,'G');
    root = Insert(root,'A');
    root = Insert(root,'H');
    root = Insert(root,'I');
    LevelOrder(root);

    return 0;

    }

struct Node* Insert(struct Node* root,char x)
{
     if (root == NULL)
     {
         root = newNode(x); 
         }
    else if (x <= root->data)
    {
        root->left = Insert(root->left, x);
        }

    else
    {
        root->right = Insert(root->right,x);
        }
    return root;
}

struct Node* newNode(char x)
{
    struct Node* temp1 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
    temp1->data = x;
    temp1->right = NULL;
    temp1->left = NULL;
    return  temp1;
    }


void enq(struct Node* temproot)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = temproot->data;
    temp->right = temp->left= NULL;

    if(front == NULL && rear == NULL)
    {
        front = rear = temp;
        return;
        }
    rear->right = temp;
    rear = temp;
    }

struct Node* deq()
{
    struct Node* temp = front;
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        printf("The queue is empty!");
        }
    else if (rear == front)
    {

        front = rear = NULL;
        }
    else
    {
        front = front->right;
        }
    return temp;
    }

void LevelOrder(struct Node* root)
{
    struct Node* temproot = root;

    while(temproot != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c ", temproot->data);
        if(temproot->left != NULL)
        {enq(temproot->left);
            }
        if (temproot->right !=NULL)
        {enq(temproot->right);
            }
        temproot = deq();
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to use your debugger?

Comment: Quote: " I am not getting the required output" Hmmm, okay... so what output did you get? And what did you expect?

Comment: It showed no errors. On running the program, I get infinite 'G' as my output. I expected to get all the characters (which I had input in the main function) to be printed in some order.

Comment: @RohitBajaj edit your question with that information. And also the expected output

Comment: Where is your basic 'print the data in the tree' function?  You need one.  You should use it to ensure the tree is built correctly.

Comment: Your queue needs to enqueue pointers to nodes in your search tree.  You're trying to reuse your `Node` structure for this, which you could just about get away if you decided, for example, that the left pointer pointed to the node (the `temproot` you pass to `enq()`) and the right pointer pointed to the next node in the queue.  But, AFAICT, that's not what you're doing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am trying hard but not able to figure out. Am I just complicating things way too much in this code? should I try a different approach altogether?

Comment: I've not tested it, but maybe (just maybe), you need to replace `temp->data = temproot->data;
    temp->right = temp->left= NULL;` in `enq()` with `temp->left = temproot; temp->right = NULL;` — and then in `deq()` you should have `struct Node *next = temp->left; free(temp); return next;`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thankyou. WIll try it out and let you know. I know the code is really messy. Thank you for spending so much of your time on it :)

Comment: Your system of indenting the close brace `}` one level more than the open brace `{` is very unusual (but remarkably consistent) — I've not seen it before.  I don't think it helps readability.  It is certainly not an orthodox [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).  It is closest to Allman (my preferred style), but that has the close brace at the same level of indentation as the open brace.  I strongly recommend either Allman or 1TBS style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need to enqueue the pointers to the nodes in the tree structures — not the data.  You can do this by using the `left` element to point to the node and the `right` element to point to the next item in the queue.

In the comments, I said:

> I've not tested it, but maybe (just maybe), you need to replace
>
> ```
> temp->data = temproot->data;
> temp->right = temp->left= NULL;
> ```
>
> in `enq()` with
>
> ```
> temp->left = temproot;
> temp->right = NULL;
> ```
>
> and then in `deq()` you should have
>
> ```
> struct Node *next = temp->left;
> free(temp);
> return next;
> ```

This seems to be the correct prescription.  This code has a function `dump_BST` that dumps the data in the tree for debugging purposes (and an auxilliary function `dump_BST_node()` that implements a pre-order traversal while printing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *left;
};

void enq(struct Node *temproot);
struct Node *deq(void);
struct Node *Insert(struct Node *, char x);
struct Node *newNode(char data);
void LevelOrder(struct Node *root);
void dump_BST(const char *tag, const struct Node *node);

struct Node *front = NULL;
struct Node *rear = NULL;

int main(void)
{
    struct Node *root = NULL;
    dump_BST("Empty", root);
    root = Insert(root, 'F');
    dump_BST("Added F", root);
    root = Insert(root, 'B');
    dump_BST("Added B", root);
    root = Insert(root, 'C');
    //dump_BST("Added C", root);
    root = Insert(root, 'D');
    //dump_BST("Added D", root);
    root = Insert(root, 'E');
    //dump_BST("Added E", root);
    root = Insert(root, 'G');
    //dump_BST("Added G", root);
    root = Insert(root, 'A');
    //dump_BST("Added A", root);
    root = Insert(root, 'H');
    //dump_BST("Added H", root);
    root = Insert(root, 'I');
    dump_BST("Added I", root);
    LevelOrder(root);

    return 0;
}

struct Node *Insert(struct Node *root, char x)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = newNode(x);
    }
    else if (x <= root->data)
    {
        root->left = Insert(root->left, x);
    }

    else
    {
        root->right = Insert(root->right, x);
    }
    return root;
}

struct Node *newNode(char x)
{
    struct Node *temp1 = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp1->data = x;
    temp1->right = NULL;
    temp1->left = NULL;
    return temp1;
}

void enq(struct Node *temproot)
{
    struct Node *temp = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->left = temproot;
    temp->data = 'Z';

    if (front == NULL && rear == NULL)
    {
        front = rear = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->right = temp;
        rear = temp;
    }
}

struct Node *deq(void)
{
    struct Node *temp = front;
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        printf("The queue is empty!\n");
    }
    else if (rear == front)
    {
        front = rear = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        front = front->right;
    }
    struct Node *next = (temp == NULL) ? NULL : temp->left;
    free(temp);
    return next;
}

void LevelOrder(struct Node *root)
{
    struct Node *temproot = root;

    while (temproot != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c ", temproot->data);
        if (temproot->left != NULL)
        {
            enq(temproot->left);
        }
        if (temproot->right != NULL)
        {
            enq(temproot->right);
        }
        temproot = deq();
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

static void dump_BST_nodes(const struct Node *node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        printf("Node: '%c' (ptr = %p, left = %p, right = %p)\n",
                node->data, (void *)node, (void *)node->left, (void *)node->right);
        dump_BST_nodes(node->left);
        dump_BST_nodes(node->right);
    }
}

void dump_BST(const char *tag, const struct Node *node)
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    dump_BST_nodes(node);
    printf("%s: end\n", tag);
}
```

When run, this produces:

```
Empty:
Empty: end
Added F:
Node: 'F' (ptr = 0x7fc63fc02750, left = 0x0, right = 0x0)
Added F: end
Added B:
Node: 'F' (ptr = 0x7fc63fc02750, left = 0x7fc63fc02770, right = 0x0)
Node: 'B' (ptr = 0x7fc63fc02770, left = 0x0, right = 0x0)
Added B: end
Added I:
Node: 'F' (ptr = 0x7fc63fc02750, left = 0x7fc63fc02770, right = 0x7fc63fc027f0)
Node: 'B' (ptr = 0x7fc63fc02770, left = 0x7fc63fc02810, right = 0x7fc63fc02790)
Node: 'A' (ptr = 0x7fc63fc02810, left = 0x0, right = 0x0)
Node: 'C' (ptr = 0x7fc63fc02790, left = 0x0, right = 0x7fc63fc027b0)
Node: 'D' (ptr = 0x7fc63fc027b0, left = 0x0, right = 0x7fc63fc027d0)
Node: 'E' (ptr = 0x7fc63fc027d0, left = 0x0, right = 0x0)
Node: 'G' (ptr = 0x7fc63fc027f0, left = 0x0, right = 0x7fc63fc02830)
Node: 'H' (ptr = 0x7fc63fc02830, left = 0x0, right = 0x7fc63fc02850)
Node: 'I' (ptr = 0x7fc63fc02850, left = 0x0, right = 0x0)
Added I: end
F B G A C H D I E The queue is empty!
```

You'll need to clean up the code — the message that the queue is empty is a nuisance, and you won't need the debugging printing.  But that does show how I did go about checking the code (the fact that it worked OK the first time through was an unexpected but pleasant bonus).